# Is there a way I can concatenate two columns with different functions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way I can concatenate two columns with different functions?

From the example, can I make it look like Q3 2015

[image]

```
SELECT convert(varchar(20), [Evaluation Date],(101)),
       month([Evaluation Date]), year([Evaluation Date]), 
       case when month([Evaluation Date]) in ('1','2','3') then 'Q1'
            when month([Evaluation Date]) in ('4','5','6') then 'Q2'
            when month([Evaluation Date]) in ('7','8','9') then 'Q3'
            when month([Evaluation Date]) in ('10','11','12') then 'Q4'
       end as [Month],
       year([Evaluation Date]) as [Year], 
       DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [Evaluation Date]), 0) AS MonthYear,
```

Comment: Also, to whomever downvoted this question, please provide explanation why next time

Comment: @AceTrajkov I didn't downvote the question, but there is no requirement that someone must provide a reason for it.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a requirement, think of it more as a common courtesy.
If a question is downvoted, it means there is something lacking, whether more information, or as basic as "google it, ******"
Providing that reason can help the poster and others that read the question with better insight for the next question they post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get `Q YYYY`, then the easiest way is to use `datename()`:

```
select ('Q' + datename(quarter, [Evaluation Date]) + ' ' +
        datename(year, [Evaluation Date])
       ) as QYYYY
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT convert(varchar(20), [Evaluation Date],(101)),
   month([Evaluation Date]), year([Evaluation Date]), 
   case when month([Evaluation Date]) in ('1','2','3') then 'Q1'
        when month([Evaluation Date]) in ('4','5','6') then 'Q2'
        when month([Evaluation Date]) in ('7','8','9') then 'Q3'
        when month([Evaluation Date]) in ('10','11','12') then 'Q4'
   end + ' ' + CONVERT(nvarchar, year([Evaluation Date]))
```